# How are Stack Exchange engine updates deployed to production?

Tags: discussion, implementation, deployment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is Stack Overflow's deployment process?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7406/what-is-stack-overflows-deployment-process)

I'm just wondering, how does the Stack Exchange team deploy updates to production? As you have multiple servers, what strategy do you use? Here's some that I have heard of:

- Put up an App_Offline page for a minute or two while you quickly deploy the new build to all of the servers
- Deploy the build to the servers one-by-one without taking all of them offline at once

Comment: are you asking about the SO/SE team, or just teams in general?

Comment: @Popular updated my post to clarify. Thanks!

Comment: thanks. I was going to vote to close because it was an SO question, but then I realized you could be asking about SE specifically. As Jon pointed out, though, there is another question that this is a dupe of. So, still voting to close, for that reason.