# Does Stack Exchange still use SVN for their code base?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, source-code

Recently I used [svn-revision](/questions/tagged/svn-revision) tag in my question on MSE and fell in thoughts: does SE still use SVN versioning system for their code base as described in the tag?

> This is for any kind of question that is somehow related to SVN revision numbers of the StackExchange network

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, according to [this tweet](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/855441395502415874) from [Nick Craver](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/135201/nick-craver), SE Architecture lead, they are now on Git, backed by GitHub Enterprise.

From that tweet:

> Stack Overflow source control history:
>
> - local hard drives
> - SVN
> - Hg
> - raw git server
> - Kiln
> - GitLab
> - GitHub Enterprise

In [his answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/248148/158100) [Oded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/140505/oded) explains how the revision number is created:

> `year.month.day.teamcity-build-number`
>
> The `teamcity-build-number` is essentially an internal number that Team
>   City maintains. It is essentially the number of times a specific build
>   configuration has run (either automatically or by manual button click)

I think it is safe to conclude that the rev. shown in the footer of each page has nothing to do anymore with subversion revisions, assuming it ever had.

Comment: Should the mentioned tag be renamed in this case?

Comment: @alexolut maybe, suggestions?

Comment: probably [tag:se-revision] to prevent renaming due to possible changes of versioning system in the future.

Comment: @alexolut I'm not sold on that one. Can't it just be revision or revision-number?

Comment: they could be confusing with post revisions I think

Comment: Hmm, you have a point there. Naming things is hard.

Comment: In the tavern there are votes for doing nothing, as in: leave the tag as is.

Comment: In the data explorer source code, there are still some remains of a mercurial (some `.hg*` files in the source root).

Comment: Right, the .hgignore file is still there. Might become handy when Mercurial becomes trendy again in 6 to 8 years ...

Comment: Years after, which made me land on this answer, another possibly left over: the `span` holding the current version used for the site have, as identifier, `svnrev`.